# R: label box in a plot is not reduced with font size

Tags: r, plot, label, legend

When I reduce the font size of my legend, the box around the legend is not reduced with it, meaning that it looks really ugly.

I use the following code:

```
barplot(transComp,space=c(0,2),legend.text=TRUE,beside=TRUE,horiz=TRUE,
col=c("red1","red4","green3"),
xlab="crimes per 100,000 inhabitants",
axes=TRUE, names.arg=colnamesbarplot, cex.names=0.5, las=1,
args.legend=list(cex=0.4,
x="bottomright"))
```

So the name of my data is "transComp" and the names of each bar-group are taken from "colnamesbarplot".

Using `omi` and `mar` does not seem to work, since they do not relate to the box around the labels? I would also be fine just with having no box at all, if that is easy to solve...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You could include `bty = "n"` in your list passed to `args.legend` and remove the box - rather than try and resize it.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce using a modified example from in `?barplot.default`, so it may have something to do with a different function specific to whatever unstated class of object 'transComp' might be. With `barplot.defualt`, when you pass `trace=TRUE` in the args.legend you might at least get screen output of the locations of the corners of the "rect" object. As always reproducible examples get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by including `bty="n"` in list to `args.legend`, just as @Dayne proposed. The code therefore now looks like

```
barplot(transComp,space=c(0,2),legend.text=TRUE,beside=TRUE,horiz=TRUE,
col=c("red1","red4","green3"), xlab="crimes per 100,000 inhabitants",
axes=TRUE, names.arg=colnamesbarplot, cex.names=0.5, las=1, args.legend=list(cex=0.4, 
x="bottomright", bty = "n"))
```

I consider this question answered and will also try to illustrate my problems with reproducable examples, as @DWNin suggested.

Thank you!